# Convert Non-Ascii into unicode characters

Tags: perl

I need to convert Non-ASCII characters into Unicode Values using perl programming:

,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,     ,

= \U+1D6B2 (&#x1D6B2) ....

The above characters are in double-struck or fraktur however I could not able convert these into Unicode values. If any modules available please point out.

Some one could help me on this one.

```
my @arry = qw(                                                                                                                                                                               );

foreach my $sng(@arry)
{
    my $newsng =  ord($sng);
    #print "$sng\t$newsng\t";
    $newsng = sprintf("%x", $newsng);
    #print "$newsng\n";
    $incnt=~s/$sng/$newsng/esg || print "NOT: $sng\n";
}

print $incnt;
```

Its not printing the unicode values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use utf8;
use feature 'unicode_strings';

printf "%x\n", ord('');
# => 1D6B2
```

More details on Unicode in Perl: [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html).

Comment: thanks for your coding. However I couldn't print the values in text files. I don't where is my mistake. Added in the summary...

Comment: Add `use encoding 'utf-8';`.

Comment: ð”„, : its replacing some of the junks.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that your program expects the input to be utf8 bytes and that the output filehandle expects to receive utf8 bytes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
# Automatically decode data from filehandles
use open ':encoding(utf8)';

# Tell STDOUT we'll be writing utf8
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

open my $utf8_fh, '<', 'utf8.txt' or die $!;

while (<$utf8_fh>) {
  chomp;

  foreach my $c (split) {
    printf "$c: %x\n", ord($c);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
: 1d49c
: 1d49e
: 1d49f
: 1d4a2
: 1d4a5
...
```